# Script to install latest kernel

Tags: kernel, scripts

Does anyone know of a script to install the latest mainline Linux kernel from the Ubuntu kernel mainline ppa? Preferably one that auto-runs on login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of exactly what you are looking for, and how to use it!

Run:

```
git clone git://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater
bash Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater/install
```

Then run for the latest:

```
KernelUpdateChecker -no-rc -v 4.6.3 -r yakkety
/tmp/kernel-update
```

And follow the prompts!

Or for the latest Xenial:

```
KernelUpdateChecker -no-rc -r xenial 
/tmp/kernel-update
```

And follow the prompts!

To run this on login, search for startup applications, and edit the entry KernelUpdateChecker (I think that is what it is or something similar) and change it to the first command (e.g. `KernelUpdateChecker -no-rc -r xenial`.) It will tell you if there is a new kernel avaliable and to run `/tmp/kernel-update`.